# How to translate image on xaxis

Tags: python, image, pyqtgraph

I am currently plotting a spectrogram using a pyqtgraph imageitem. I've scaled it so it matches the bandwidth of my collection but I am trying to offset it so that the signal will read exactly the frequency it collected.

IE: Signal collected is in the MHz range, downconverted and resampled at 500KHz. So when plotting I scale so that the x-axis shows 0-500Khz but I need 10.5Mhz +/- 250Khz.

I've looked at translate and tried an offset of 250Khz just to check and it offsets it to a center of 976.8Mhz, which I'm not sure how it got that.

```py
img.translate(0,250*(10**3))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else needs help

dx needs to be in terms of the scale. IE

```
img.translate(0,dx/xscale)
```